# Accurev: change package merge required

Tags: accurev

I've got a workspace backed to my collaboration stream (CS), the CS has a parent stream (Parent).

In my workspace I changed a file with version Parent/1 and then promoted it to the collaboration stream some times. Its version became CS/2.

Then I got an update from the Parent and found that I don't need to keep my changes in that file and purged it on the CS. Its version became "CS/2*" on the CS and "Parent/2" in my workspace.

Now I'm trying to make some changes in the file in my workspace and promote it to the CS again, but I've got the message "change package merge required" for the file.

If I understand correctly, it can't be promoted due to the file version in my workspace is not derived from CS/2. How can I resolve the issue and promote new changes to the CS?

P.S. Moreover I have a pack of such files - about 70 files. How can I resolve the problem for the whole pack of files?

Answer (score 3):

Open the issue you are associating your promotion with.
Click on Changes tab.
Select the file from the list in changes tab.
Right click -> Remove.
Now promote using this issue.

Comment: Should I do it for each file from the file list?

Comment: Anyway it seems like it doesn't work. "The version to be promoted does not contain all the changes in the specified issue record"

Comment: What is the output from the following command?  "accurev cpkdescribe -I <issue number> -p <depotname>"    What is the name of the file you removed?  Are you just promoting this file or including others?

Comment: This worked for me. I did it for every file in the change list that I had a conflict with

Answer (score 2):

the only way that i have found to fix this is to use the "send to>issue (specifying ancestor)" command from the version browser tree.

1. open accurev
2. **view>view streams** (pick your depot)
3. click the "active issues" icon in the upper-right corner
4. click the **"show active issues"** icon under the problem stream
5. right-click>**"send to change palatte"** on the source issue
6. right-click>**"browse versions"** on the problem file
7. select "everything" in the "show" dropdown
8. **right-click>"send to">"issue (specifying basis)"** on the latest version in the current stream
9. click on the earliest ancestor (this should be a common ancestor of all versions)
10. enter the target ticket number and click "ok"

these steps should work for any source/target issue, even "unaffiliated" changes.  technically, you shouldn't have to "show everything" and choose the oldest version. you really just need to get back to a common ancestor.